# How to plot bars such that for value less than a threshold value are in an opposite direction than the ones greater?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

This is the graph in question:

[image]
For reference this is the type of graph I am trying to achieve.

[image: This is the graph in question]

In the reference graph above, the bars below correspond to negative values and are hence in the opposite direction. So, I tried to set all values to their corresponding negative values for plotting purposes. But, as an output, I get all the bars of same length:

[image]

This is the code I used to plot the graph in Seaborn:

```py
import unicodedata # to print pound sign

# Set the plot style and colour palette to use (remember dodgy spelling if you're from the UK!)
sns.set(style='whitegrid')
sns.set_color_codes('muted')
sns.set(font_scale=2)

 
# Initialize the matplotlib figure (f) and axes (ax), and set width and height of the plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
# ax.set_xlim(-90,103)
# ax.set_xticks(range(9,103))
 
# Create the plot, choosing the variables for each axis, the data source and the colour (b = blue)
# show_values_on_bars(ax, h_v="v", space=0.4)
sns_t= sns.barplot(x='Final Team Value', y='Name', 
                   data=final_bank_value,
                   palette='Spectral')
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    ax.text(width -0.7  ,
            p.get_y()+p.get_height()/2. + 0.2,
            '{}{:1.2f}'.format(unicodedata.lookup("Pound Sign"),width), ha="left")

# Rename the axes, setting y axis label to be blank
ax.set(ylabel='', xlabel='Final Value of Team')
 
# Remove the borders from the plot
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create negative data at a certain threshold, we used the following method I've run the code to draw your graph based on that data and attached the graph drawn.

```
import pandas as pd
import unicodedata

final_bank_value = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['nameA','nameB','nameC','nameD'],'Final Team Value':[250,289,55,15]}, index=[0,1,2,3])
final_bank_value['Final Team Value'] = final_bank_value['Final Team Value'].apply(lambda x: x * -1 if x <= 100 else x)
final_bank_value


Name    Final Team Value
0   nameA   250
1   nameB   289
2   nameC   -55
3   nameD   -15
```

[image]

Comment: I plotted the graph with negative values like you did. But, in mine although the bars change direction all my bars turn out to be of same length when I plot it with negative values. I have attached the resulting graph in my original question.

Comment: It's not just that the three negative values in the posted graphs are close numbers, so they look the same ? How about trying to change the values?

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. Thanks for the help.